# How to query posts of certain category in WordPress 6 Block Theme?

Tags: php, wordpress

I specified category id as follows, but still query all posts, not posts in category 4 (term_id).

```
<!-- wp:query {"query":{"category":4,"perPage":0,"pages":0,"offset":0,"postType":"post","order":"desc","orderBy":"date","author":"","search":"","exclude":[],"sticky":"","inherit":false}} -->
    <!-- wp:post-template -->
        <!-- wp:post-title {"isLink":true} /-->
    <!-- /wp:post-template -->
<!-- /wp:query -->
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Firstly, go to visual mode in the WP block editor.
2. Select Query loop block in the editor
3. In inspector control (on the right side of text editor) select Block panel
4. Under Block panel, go to Filters (click the + icon)
5. Select `Taxonomies` option, then type the desired category name
6. Make sure now the query loop only shows the filtered posts
7. Now turn the editor mode to code editor, you will see the taxQuery like this

   `<!-- wp:query { ... "taxQuery":{"category":[23]}}} -->`

[image: Query Loop Filter Option]

---

Source from Gutenberg:

- https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/v17.5.1/packages/block-library/src/post-template/edit.js#L89

Function which build `WP_Query` arguments from the block's JSON data:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/build_query_vars_from_query_block/

`tax_query` array formation from block's attribute `query.taxQuery`:

- https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.4/src/wp-includes/blocks.php#L1764-L1775

Snippet:

```
if ( ! empty( $block->context['query']['taxQuery'] ) ) {
    $query['tax_query'] = array();
    foreach ( $block->context['query']['taxQuery'] as $taxonomy => $terms ) {
        if ( is_taxonomy_viewable( $taxonomy ) && ! empty( $terms ) ) {
            $query['tax_query'][] = array(
                'taxonomy'         => $taxonomy,
                'terms'            => array_filter( array_map( 'intval', $terms ) ),
                'include_children' => false,
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thx, i post my solution below.

Comment: @WisdomFusion yes, you have to pass the value as array.

Answer (score 1):

thx, i fix it using:

```
<!-- wp:query {"query": {"categoryIds": [4], "perPage": 0, "pages": 0, "offset": 0, "postType": "post", "order": "ASC", "orderBy": "date"}} -->
    <!-- wp:post-template -->
        <!-- wp:post-title {"isLink": true} /-->
    <!-- /wp:post-template -->
<!-- /wp:query -->
```

Comment: FYI, Internally `categoryIds` also converted to tax_query for BC. Ref: https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.4/src/wp-includes/blocks.php#L1745